# Induced map from a complex of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C$ be a complex of $R$-modules, where we label the maps $f$ and $g$, respectively.

Why is the sequence $0\longrightarrow H(B)\longrightarrow \text{coker}(f)\longrightarrow \text{im}(g)\longrightarrow 0$ exact? (where $H(B)$ is $\text{ker}(g)/\text{im}(f)$, the cohomology of the sequence at $B$.)

How do we even get the two internal maps, let alone exactness?

Comment: $ker(g) = ker(f)$ so isn't $H(B) = 0$? Then $coker(f) = B/im(f) = B/ker(g) = im(g)$ so the sequence is exact.

Comment: @NoelLundström Sorry, that was a mistake. The sequence is a complex, not exact. We just assume $gf=0$.

Comment: No worries, that's what I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a sequence

$$0\to\ker(g)\hookrightarrow B\xrightarrow{g}\text{im}(g)\to 0$$

which is clearly exact. Furthermore, $\text{im}(f)\subseteq\ker(g)\subseteq B$ and $\text{im}(f)$ is mapped to $0$ by $g$ since $gf=0$, so we have an induced surjective map $\text{coker}(f)=B/\text{im}(f)\xrightarrow{\bar{g}}\text{im}(g)$. The map $\ker(g)\to\text{coker}(f)$ (which is the composition of the inclusion map $\ker(g)\hookrightarrow B$ and the projection map $B\to B/\text{im}(f)$) has kernel $\text{im}(f)=H(B)$, so we have the induced injective map $H(B)=\ker(g)/\text{im}(f)\to\text{coker}(f)$. Then, by the exactness of the first sequence, we conclude that

$$0\to H(B)\to\text{coker}(f)\xrightarrow{\bar{g}} \text{im}(g)\to 0$$

is exact.

Comment: Doesn't $f$ have to be a monomorphism in order for the cokernel to be a quotient? Also, you say "injective", but a function can be a monomorphism and still not injective, right?

Comment: @ponchan In the category of $R$-modules, "monomorphism" and "injection" are equivalent notions. More generally, injections are monomorphisms in any concrete category and converse also holds if there exist free objects.

Answer (score 2):

[Anonymous](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/559302/anonymous)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3711847/90543) is correct (+1), I just like diagrams, so I thought I'd provide one.

We have the diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\newcommand\im{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand\coker{\operatorname{coker}}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \im f @>1_{\im f}>> \im f @>>> 0 @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> \ker g @>>> B @>>> \im g @>>> 0,
\end{CD}
$$
which has exact rows, and the vertical maps are all injective. Therefore, when we apply 
snake lemma, we get an exact sequence (of the cokernels of the vertical maps)
$$ 0 \to H(B) \to \coker f \to \im g \to 0.$$